# Winform C# Datagridview paint header

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, paint

I want to customize my datagridviews in windows forms using c#. What I want to do is to Paint the datagrid header with a gradient I made:

```
public void Colorear_Barra_abajo(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0,0, panel_Borde_abajo.Width, panel_Borde_abajo.Height);

        if (r.Width > 0 && r.Height > 0)
        {
            Color c1 = Color.FromArgb(255, 54, 54, 54);
            Color c2 = Color.FromArgb(255, 62, 62, 62);
            Color c3 = Color.FromArgb(255, 98, 98, 98);

            LinearGradientBrush br = new LinearGradientBrush(r, c1, c3, 90, true);
            ColorBlend cb = new ColorBlend();
            cb.Positions = new[] { 0, (float)0.5, 1 };
            cb.Colors = new[] { c1, c2 , c3 };
            br.InterpolationColors = cb;

            // paint
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, r);
        }
    }
```

The issue is that datagridviews does not have paint event so i can´t use this. Is there any way to paint the header with a gradient? Or the only way is to select one backcolor?

Thanks..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you mean `Column Header`, yes. in the `CellPainting Event`

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1)
        {
            Color c1 = Color.FromArgb(255, 54, 54, 54);
            Color c2 = Color.FromArgb(255, 62, 62, 62);
            Color c3 = Color.FromArgb(255, 98, 98, 98);

            LinearGradientBrush br = new LinearGradientBrush(e.CellBounds, c1, c3, 90, true);
            ColorBlend cb = new ColorBlend();
            cb.Positions = new[] { 0, (float)0.5, 1 };
            cb.Colors = new[] { c1, c2, c3 };
            br.InterpolationColors = cb;


            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.CellBounds);
            e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```